# Figure margins too large when trying to use layout()

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I have this data set

```
wine <-read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data",sep=",")
attach(wine)
```

And I want to use the layout function for prompting six scatterplots each one of them with its histogram above, but when trying to put the first scatterplot with its own histogram above this error occurs:

```
> m<-rbind(c(2,4,6),c(1,3,5),c(8,10,12),c(7,9,11))
> layout.show(layout(m))
> layout(m)
> plot(V2[1:25]~V5[1:25]);with(wine, hist(V5))
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

I tried using `png("1.png",800,600)`, the  file gets created but it tells me that I do not have permissions to see the content of the file.

Comment: Try increasing the dimensions of the device.

Comment: I get the same results

Comment: you can simply adjust the plot window manually in your R Studio ... that'll do the job .

Comment: or simply decrease params related to margin, such as `par(mar = c(3, 3, 1.5, 0.4), mgp = c(1.5, 0.4, 0), tck = - 0.05)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the dimensions of the device. This works just fine on my system:

```
png("test.png", width = 1000, height = 1000)

layout(m)
plot(V2 ~ V5, data = wine[1:25,])
with(wine, hist(V5))

dev.off() #you need to close the device to open the file in other software
```